# Allow an edit reviewer to change a vote to approve to an edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

If a reviewer votes to approve a suggested edit, but the edit has not yet been approved by a second reviewer, the original reviewer should be allowed to change their mind, improving the edit rather than approving it.

Comment: Interval between two reviews of the edit is usually quite short, no?

Comment: @GrigoryM, the recent notification feature may in fact make this request obsolete-on-arrival. The main concern is during periods of very low activity.

Comment: Do you have evidence that the time between approvals, during periods of low activity, has much of a bad effect?  It doesn't seem to me like a feature worth adding.